# (Ejecutar un Formulario(JinternalFrame) desde otro Formulario(Jinternal) con un Boton ) Estan Contenidos en FormPrincipal q tene JDesktopPanel

Tags: java

Tengo un formulario Principal que contiene un JDestopPanel (DPanelcontrol) cuando se ejecuta el programa enm la parte superior del formulario hay boton que llama al form Frm_Listapacientes(JinternalFrame) y este tiene un boton (Nuevo Paciente) ...y tengo otro form Form_Pacientes.
Entonces yo presiono el boton (Nuevo Paciente) y oculto el Formulario (Frm_Listapacientes) y debe ejecutarme el Form(Form_Pacientes) dentro del DPanelcontrol . esto lo realizo con el siguiente codigo.

- Este codigo lo tengo en boton (Nuevo Paciente)-------
  '     '

Form_Pacientes  hijo = new Form_Pacientes( 0, 0,0, 0);
MenuPrincipal.DPanelcontrol.add(hijo);

```
 //maximizar el JinternalFrame
   try {
       hijo.setMaximum(true);
   } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Pantalla_Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
    this.setVisible(false);    
   hijo.setVisible(true);
```

Pero no se muestra el formulario . muchas gracias de antemano